# how to capture "DROP"ped packets on OUTPUT of iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, tcpdump

having a fairly complex `OUTPUT` processing on `iptables`, how does one go about capturing / displaying (at least similarly to how `tcpdump` captures them) the packets that were to leave through an interface, but are `DROP`ped instead in various places of `iptables` `OUTPUT`/`FORWARD` chain processing?

( since these packets do not appear on the physical interface, perhaps one cannot use `tcpdump`, right? )

( the best i could come up with was changing in all iptables the "DROP" target to something that would forward all such to-be-dropped packets to a virtual/fake interface, and running tcpdump on this interface - it just seems like a lot of work though. and i still am not clear on how to cause ONLY such packets to go this fake interface - "route" would cause ALL packets for such IPs to go to the fake, but i need only the to-be-`DROP`ped packets to go there )

***update***: *embarrassed* almost-same Q has been asked already at another forum and answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174107/record-contents-of-packets-dropped-in-iptables */embarrassed* ; the only improvement i could ask for would be to not have to put the log rule `NFLOG` before / instead of   every possible `DROP` rule. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a good idea to log every dropped packet, so you can debug even transient problems with ease.

I usually create a new 'target' that combines the two:

`iptables -N drop
iptables -j NFLOG
iptables -j DROP`

Then use `-j drop` as a drop in replacement for `DROP`.